# Apache not displaying PHP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, wamp

Basically, I have installed both WAMP and XAMPP (two different times) and none of them seem to display PHP, looking on the internet it must be Apache.

I dont have world web service thing active, I don't have Skype installed, I have even changed the port to 8080 and nothing seems to work.

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: You need to add more data to be more clear.
As I recall, xampp takes care of things in installation by default.
Maybe you have some other server active.

Does it serve static html?

Comment: no other server running, displays static html, just will not display php files of anykind ive even put <?php text text ?> and it will not display

Comment: Exactly how do you access those files? Did you use localhost:8080 ?

Comment: Have no idea. Are you sure that your server displays regular html on http:// protocol?

It shouldn't be cause both wamp and xampp should have php properly configured.

Comment: localhost:8080 is making it work now, i have no idea why i can just click a view

Comment: The port 80 is a standard TCP port for HTTP requests. When you type the address in a browser, it automatically uses the port 80. But if you configure a web server to listen on another port (in your case 8080), you have to tell the browser what port it needs to send the request to (again, 8080).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used localhost:8080 it seems to have solved the problem.